# Will SYSTEM_USER return the unique user id for users authenticated by Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to set up Active Directory authentication for my users, who will be assigned to specific database roles. I also need to log activity and ensure I have captured the IDs of the indivudals connected.

I have found simple instructions on how to do it. ( [How do I assign an entire Active Directory group security access in SQL Server 2008?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2572) )

... But Will SYSTEM_USER return the logon id of the active directory connection or the individual user? (Unfortunately I cannot test this!)

Comment: What is getuserid()?

Comment: There is no built-in getuserid() function in SQL.  Are you talking about the `GETUSERID()` function available in Report Builder (for Reporting Services)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx

Comment: Sorry, My Bad - I meant SYSTEM_USER

Answer (score 2):

A call to `system_user` will return the AD user's name in your case.  For instance, if you have a user set up as **YourDomain\YourUser1**:

```
select system_user

-- this returns "YourDomain\YourUser1"
```

If **YourDomain\YourUser1** is part of a AD group (i.e. **YourDomain\YourGroup1**), then it would still have the same output as above (*returning **"YourDomain\YourUser1"***).

Comment: Jon - I didn't spot the link you posted earlier. No reference to AD but a good reference to know about, thanks.