# sql web-application Connection String for member of a domain group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, active-directory

In my testing environment, I have a local sql express (2008R) server instance.  I've [created a domain group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2) and given it a [login in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server?lq=1).

But now, how do I consctruct the connection string for my web-application?  Do I give it the username and password of one of the members of the group?

And, what do I put for a "user" in the Database security section?  The group itself doesn't have a password.

Do I have to add the service account from the application pool to the AD group?

Here is what I have for a connection string; but this allows all connections, it seems:

```
<add name="development" connectionString="server=myserver\sqlexpress;
    database=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;
    Trusted_Connection=True; Pooling=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Comment: I just edited the connection string so that it doesn't have horizontal scroll bars.  Just easier to read that way.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I just pressed <Enter> wherever I wanted a new line, then indented the next line by 4 spaces.  Creates a code block...

Comment: I'm going to recommend moving this question to the main StackOverflow site since it is more programming related; this site is for database administration.

Comment: Okay.  I asked here because I figured it was the first step to administration...  but it won't bother me if it gets moved.

Comment: No problem, don't worry about posting here if you are unsure!  We welcome everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the IIS Application Pool to use the identity (domain user) you created.

My example below shows the default, out-of-the-box configuration.  You'd need to choose 'Configurable' and specify the username and password there.

Then you need to configure the site to use the AppPool.

[image]

The connection string would then be:

```
server=myserver\sqlexpress;database=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;
Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=True; Pooling=True
```

Just like you have it.

Comment: Hi, Mr. Vernon; what if, on my dev machine, the service is the VS virtual server - it's not in iis?

Comment: Good question.  There must a similar way to do this.  Perhaps you need to start Visual Studio as the user that has access to the database.  I'm not certain.

Comment: I just fired up VS... will see if there is a way to do.

Comment: I understand what you mean, though for the application pool - that will probably work on the server.  I'll try and see if I can get VS to run in IIS on my dev machine instead of using the virtual server - and see what happens.

Comment: Problem is that I can't add a local service account (VS) to a domain group...

Comment: Yeah, it appears you'd want to install the full IIS product on your workstation, and configure VS to use it.  That way you are closely mimicking the production environment.

Comment: Unless I could change the account used by the VS virtual server, no?

Comment: I would try running Visual Studio as the domain user account you specified in SQL Server.  Start Visual Studio from a command prompt using `RUNAS ...`

Comment: Okay, I hooked the site up to my IIS and changed the application pool to run on that account. But with that connection string, it seems to connect every time.  I should be able to control it with the group membership.  Now, how do I get to NOT connect so I can prove that the group membership makes a difference in the sql connection?

Comment: if you want the group to control access to Sql server, you need to remove the login from sql server and add the group itself to sql server instead.

Comment: That's what I have done, actually.  I've added the group to the logins, and mapped a user to the *group* in order to give it access to the database.  But with the connection string I have in my question, I can *always* connect, even if I remove the application pool account from the AD group.

Comment: So I set `Persist Security Info=false` and restarted the app pool, but it still connects.

Comment: you may need to run iisreset to recycle iis

Comment: That doesn't do it either.  How is it getting access?  This is hard!

Comment: I posted a link in Stack Exchange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115382/using-sspi-how-to-make-my-webapp-not-connect-to-local-sql-express