# Add a DL as a login in azure sql managed instace

Tags: sql-server, users, logins, active-directory, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am able to add individual AD logins as a login in azure sql managed instance, when i try to add a DL is the same way i am getting the following error.

**error:** Principal '' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.

**Query user:** CREATE LOGIN [] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
GO

Want to add a DL as login so that all individuals withing the DL can access the instance, isn't  this not possible?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By "DL" do you mean that the AAD Group is an "Office 365 Group" and not a "Security Group".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal

Comment: See [How do I assign an entire Active Directory group security access in SQL Server 2008?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2) for a simple rundown of how this should work. I suspect that this only works for security groups (which are the only type of group I have used this for), but I haven't confirmed this.

Comment: by the replies i assume we can give permission to only security groups? What is the difference between Office 365 Group and Security Group?

Answer (score 2):

To create a DL (assuming it is a group in AAD), you need to create without the @domain.. on the database that you want to connect.. example:

CREATE USER [GroupName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER

Here you have a link

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-23-how-to-add-aad-security-groups-to-azure-sql/ba-p/368866